# ¿Cómo eliminar un textarea por su id colocando un botón a su lado?

Tags: php, html, jquery

Estoy tratando de eliminar un `TextArea` al darle `click` a un botón que aparezca a su lado derecho, y claro también me gustaría que se eliminara ese botón les dejo del código, he tratado de muchas maneras pero no he podido.

```
<?php
     $myArray = explode('[x]', $direccion_entrega);
     $i = 0;
     foreach($myArray as $direccion_entrega)
     {
       $i++;
       echo '<div id="removeMe">
             <textarea class="sinresize" required  rows="1" cols="130"
              name="direccion_entrega[]"maxlength="255">'.$direccion_entrega.'</textarea>
                   <button onclick="removeDiv("removeMe");">Eliminar</button>
       </div>';

    }
?>
```

Comment: podrias añadir el código de la funcion `removeDiv()`, por favor

Comment: No tengo la funcion creada podrias darme un ejemplo me gustaria pasarle de parametro el id que genero

Comment: Quieres que se elimine el contenido que haya escrito dentro del textarea? o que se borre el textarea en si ? Te valdría que se ocultara ? Especifica un poco más porfavor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes que nada tienes un error en tu código, en `onclick="removeDiv("removeMe");"` no puedes usar comillas dobles para enviar el `id` del `div`, debes usar comillas simples pero como estás usando ya ambas comillas en el echo tendrías que hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
'<div id="removeMe">
    <textarea class="sinresize" required  rows="1" cols="130" name="direccion_entrega[]" maxlength="255">'.$direccion_entrega.'</textarea>
    <button onclick="removeDiv(' . "'removeMe'" . ');">Eliminar</button>
</div>'
```

En cuanto a la función para hacer desaparecer el elemento tienes dos opciones:

**1. Ocultarlo del DOM con estilos**

```js
function removeDiv(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div id="removeMe">
    <textarea class="sinresize" required  rows="1" cols="130" name="direccion_entrega[]" maxlength="255"></textarea>
    <button onclick="removeDiv('removeMe');">Eliminar</button>
</div>
```

**2. Eliminarlo completamente del DOM**

```js
function removeDiv(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).remove();
}
```

```html
<div id="removeMe">
    <textarea class="sinresize" required  rows="1" cols="130" name="direccion_entrega[]" maxlength="255"></textarea>
    <button onclick="removeDiv('removeMe');">Eliminar</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Me funciono era lo que buscaba y que bien que explicaras lo de que no podia enviar el id con comillas dobles, siempre se aprende algo nuevo en este sitio.

Answer (score 3):

Debes hacerlo con javascript:

**1. Vanilla:**

```
function removeDiv(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
}
```

**2. jQuery**

```
function removeDiv(id) {
    $('#'+id).hide();
}
```

Te añado una url (el enlace podría romperse), pero puedes revisarlo para que te familiarices con javascript.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_display.asp